# New to amazon RDS, need help

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds

I am new to amazon RDS. I need your kind suggestion on some questions i feel important to me:

1. How I can upload my existing database to rds? Is there any tool it provides so that I can upload my existing database file?
2. How can i will be able to connect the database with my webapp(the app is on the top of codeigniter)?

Very basic questions, hope will get some good answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you can import the SQL dump to RDS: http://www.koplowicz.com/node/609
2. To use codeigniter (php) to connect with RDS, you need this: [PHP Library for Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/code/2945?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1)

Comment: Just been doing this.  You don't need the linked SDK.  You can simply set up the correct parameters in the codeigniter confg/database.php file.  Infact, for RDS, the sdk doesn't actually appear to provide any functions for connecting to and querying the database.  An RDS database is simply a server running mysql and can be accessed just like any other mysql database on any other server.

Answer (score 2):

1. Amazon has a guide for importing data to RDS. http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933

I don't suggest importing a table larger than 1GB in size using their suggested methods. You need to split the files up for larger tables.

1. The above contributor is a little mixed up. You only need the PHP SDK library if you are using codeigniter to manage AWS their their API. Otherwise codeigniter will connect just fine to RDS without any modifications or special libraries.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning why PHP SDK is really useful for